# Why is this function not returning the value and givivg an error instead?

Tags: css, sass

```
@function pastel ($clr){
  $hue: hue($clr);
  $sat: 100%;
  $light: 90%;
  $pastel: HSL($hue, $sat, $light);
  @return $pastel;
}

//Trying to return here but it says "This at-rule is not allowed here."
&:hover {
  background-color: pastel($color-primary);
  color: $color-primary;
  }
```

This styling is applied to a .btn class and hence & is used.

Comment: Hi Razi, I'm not familiar with sass, but perhaps because you wrote funcion instead of function?

Comment: oh! That turned out to be embarrassing. Thanks either way.